# C program to evaluate e^x

Tags: c, exponential

I'm trying to write a C program that will allow me to evaluate e^x, but I am unsure whether I am on the right track. It seems to work ok for lower values of x, but beyond maybe 5 there is too much error. Just wondering if anyone can see where I've gone wrong with my code (or if my code is correct, is it possibly a problem with the PC not being able to deal with large values of n for n!).

Thanks :-)

Wadeford

```
unsigned int counter1 = 1, counter2 = 1, counter3 = 1, num, numFactorial, X;
float e, ex, x;

printf( "%s", "Enter a number: ");
scanf( "%d", &num);

printf( "%s", "Enter a value for x: ");
scanf( "%f", &x);

e = e + 2;
counter3 = num;

while ( counter3 > 1 ) {

    counter1 = counter3;
    numFactorial = counter3;
    X = x;

    while( counter1 > 1 ) {
        numFactorial = numFactorial * ( counter3 - counter2);
        counter1--;
        counter2++;
        X = X * x;
    }    
    counter2 = 1;
    e = e + ( 1 / (float) numFactorial );
    ex = ex + X * ( 1 / (float) numFactorial );
    counter3--;
}    

ex = ex + x + 1;

printf( "e to the nth order of approximation (n = %d) is: %f", num, e);
printf( "\ne^x to the nth order of approximation (n = %d) is: %f", num, ex);
```

Comment: Can you describe this method? Is it a Taylor series? If it is, the reason is that you need many more terms for the Taylor series to make a good approximation.

Comment: Indeed it is. I can only really expand it out to about 10 terms (10!) before the  program starts giving weird results.

Comment: You're likely getting some overflow/underflow -- why not use a library function for this?

Comment: 10! is too big, try `double` instead of `float`. For *exp(x)* 10 terms is not bad.

Comment: A 16-bit `unsigned` (equivalent to the minimum requirement of the standard) will overflow in computing `9!`.  A 32-bit `unsigned` will overflow in computing `13!`.   Even a 64-bit `unsigned` (few implementations exceed this) will overflow computing `21!`.    An `unsigned` overflows with well defined behaviour (modulo arithmetic) but that will cause pretty significant diversion in your code.    Converting `numFactorial` to a `float` wont fix that.  Also, your code is likely to overflow `X` pretty quickly (multiplying by `x` repeatedly) unless `x` is pretty small (i.e. not much more than `1.0`).

Comment: Undefined behavior for using the value of an object with automatic storage duration while it is indeterminate.

Comment: Thanks for your help guys :) Food for thought.

Answer (score 1):

I just tried your code, with x=3 it works up to num=19 (so 19th order in the expansion). After that the quantities diverge from their expected value. That's a problem of overflow, your numbers are too big.

If I understand correctly you want to obtain the value for the [Neper number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYe0A.jpg) and the exponential of a given number x up to a given order (num) in both series expansions.

And you do that calculating the factorial num! inside your code. 
This should not work with numbers greater than about 15, if numfactorial is an unsigned int. Just because of the representation of the numbers.
Use double, at least.

From my experience, when you need to calculate factorials, if that's what you are trying to do, use the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), that is in the library "math.h" and it's called tgamma.
If you look at the wikipedia page of the Gamma Function, you can use it to obtain the factorial of integer numbers:  num! = tgamma(num+1)

Comment: Hi, this is a problem from C: How to Program, by Deitel and Deitel. Consequently, I am trying to answer the problem only using the information contained in the chapters I have read so far - unfortunately, that doesn't include doubles, or gamma functions. So from what I hear, it makes sense that my program could only work so far before imploding. Is that fair?

Comment: Ok, I have the 6th edition of Deitel. In my edition you are referring to exercise 3.46 page 95. So, yeah, the book has not mentioned funtions, for loops, double or gamma. It mention double only in the C keywords that you can't use to name a variable.
THEN, what you did is correct, the fact you can't go up in order of the series is due to the huge numbers factorial gives you (as other has already pointed out in comments). 
Only thing to try is to cast from the beginning counter3 as float, and all the other counters.

Comment: Yep that's the one (8th Ed is 3.45, but same story). Reassuring, I was pulling my hair out that I couldn't get the program to work. Thanks:)